# maintaining div position between images

Tags: css, html, position

I have 3 `<div>`s like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|         |        div2        |        |
|  div1   |--------------------|  div3  |
|         |////////new div/////|        |
-----------////////////////////----------
```

**CSS**

```
.parentdiv{
position:relative;
}
div1,div2,div3{
position:relative
float:left}
```

I've tried to make the new `<div>` with `position:relative` and `float`
but couldn't make it .

I don't want to use `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 6):

place three divs, `float:left` or `display:inline` to each other,
and then divide the middle one into two.

```
<div class="A">
</div>
<div class="B">
     <div class="upper">
     </div>
     <div class="lower">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="C">
</div>
```

and CSS like

```
    .A,.B, .C
    {
       float:left;
       width:30%;
       height:200px;
       border:1px Solid #CCC;
    }
    .B .upper
   {
      width:100%;
      height:50%;
      background-color:Yellow;
   }
   .B .lower
   {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:Green;
   }
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra121/rbM3r/)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the interior `div` elements within a containing `div`.  If you want all of the `div` elements to be the same height you will need to specify a height on the three siblings and then specify a height of .5 * aforementioned height for each wrapped `div`.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="d1">Div1</div>
    <div id="dc">
        <div id="d2">Div 2</div>
        <div id="d3">Div 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="d4">Div4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#d1,#dc,#d4{
    float:left;
    background: red;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

#dc div{
    height: 20px;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/x64Vp/